# Publish web site: TYPE exists in both temporary ASP.NET assemblies

Tags: c#, asp.net, publishing

Not able to publish my website. While publishing my site I'm getting this error.

Any solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had similar problems with publishing websites using Visual Studio, solved by deleting my temporary ASP.NET files before publishing the site.

They'll most likely be in the "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder (and equivalent folders for other framework versions). If you're using a 64 bit version of windows, there'll also be a Framework64 folder with temporary asp.ney files in.